# Less intrusive equivalent of eightbit.me

Tags: profile-picture

If I understand well, eightbit.me is a service to transform pictures, especially for use as avatars, into "8bit"-style pictures.

Looks like this service requires access to my Twitter. Are there equivalent services that does not require this?

(Side question: Is it possible that these avatars are totally computer-generated? They seems to have a kind of artistic sense.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any other service that provides this functionality.  You could just sign up and create your Avatar and then revoke the Application access in http://twitter.com/settings/connections

You can also create these types of images using PhotoShop - a simple Google search will provide you with lots of sites with tutorials on how to do this.

According to [this article](http://www.crunchbase.com/company/eightbit-me) on CrunchBase the images are created using pure CSS & HTML.

> Eightbit.me will be a service to help
>   people create 8-bit avatars. The first
>   idea was to use images with very few
>   selections and to use pure HTML / JS
>   to create the characters.
>
> Inspired by an 8-bitted Dribbble post
>   by UK artist and designer Harry
>   Harrison, San Francisco interactive
>   designers Addison Kowalski, Amadeus
>   Demarzi and Courtney Guertin took the
>   idea to the next level by 8 bit-ing
>   their Twitter avatars, which
>   inevitably went viral among the tech
>   set. Eightbit.me is the result.

Comment: Thanks! I guess a safe and easy solution would be to create a temporary Twitter account just for this.